# Fail SELECT Query if table is locked in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, jdbc

Is there a way to fail a select query if a table is locked for access instead of waiting for the lock to be released?

I would prefer resolving it with SQL but doing it at JDBC level in the code is also OK.

I cannot use LOCK_TIMEOUT because Postgres version is too old.

basically I would like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

to fail immediately instead of waiting for this

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE SOME_TABLE IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
SELECT pg_sleep(10);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

EDIT: Version is unknown because the DBMS I'm using is actually GaussDB, PostghreSQL, but it basically behaves like Postgres since it's developed based on Postgres. So I don't know which version of Postgres my version corresponds to. SELECT VERSION() will give me Gauss version instead of Postgre version.

Comment: You can take a look at [`pg_locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) and fail if there's a lock that satisfies your criteria.

Comment: I have thought about that but wouldn't there be a chance (although slim) of the table  being locked between processing the pg_locks select result and performing the select statement?

Comment: You're right. How about `LOCK TABLE SOME_TABLE IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE`[**`NOWAIT;`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-lock.html)? The `NOWAIT` support reaches back all the way to 8.0. I'm also wondering what your use case is - why don't you want to read the snapshot made available to the `select`? Or maybe you're trying to emulate some kind of [serializable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) behaviour?

Comment: Lord knows what might be possible in an ancient but unspecified version.

Comment: @jjanes Presence of [`pg_sleep()` suggests at least 8.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/8.2.0/#:~:text=server%2Dside%20sleep%20function), lack of [9.3's `lock_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.3.0/#:~:text=configuration%20variable%20lock_timeout) suggests 9.2 tops. I agree version should be specified, and an update is long overdue.

Comment: @jjanes Yeah sorry it's GaussDB, not actaully postgres, it's developed based on Postgres (basically it's postgres), so I don't know which version of Postgres was used to develop the version I'm using, if I do Select version(); it gives me the GaussDB version which is basically useless. I would have specified the version otherwise.

Comment: @Zegarek I have a table that's refreshed every xx hours by a service and have a data cleaning job reading from it and caches it with its own interval, I can't have it read it while the table is being updated or the data would be bad. Problem is that the update cache part from the job also has its own timeout which  only considers the reading time, so if it has to wait for the lock it would most liekly time out, and adjusting time out has its own problems, so I've decided to implement my own retry mechanism in case the table is being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897757/fail-select-query-if-table-is-locked-in-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment132176401_74897757) earlier: it sounds like it's exactly what [`NOWAIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-lock.html) is for:

> ***NOWAIT***
> Specifies that LOCK TABLE should not wait for any conflicting locks to be released: if the specified lock(s) cannot be acquired immediately without waiting, the transaction is aborted.

So you should be able to replace this:

```sql
LOCK TABLE SOME_TABLE IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

With this:

```sql
LOCK TABLE SOME_TABLE IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;
```

Without the need for `pg_sleep()` and it will fail if the lock isn't available immediately.

Guessing from the fact that you're already using [8.2's `pg_sleep()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/8.2.0/#:%7E:text=server%2Dside%20sleep%20function) but don't yet have the [9.3's `lock_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.3.0/#:%7E:text=configuration%20variable%20lock_timeout), your version should be covered by [`NOWAIT` support starting with 8.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/8.0.0/#:%7E:text=Add%20NOWAIT%20option%20to%20LOCK).

Comment: Have you tried the behaviour in Postgres? It somehow behaves the same for me, the select query will still wait for the lock to be released with no wait, but if I try aquiring the lock with no wait it does work. I tried locking it with a connection and with another connection aquire an access share lock with LOCK TABLE SOME_TABLE IN ACCESS SHARE MODE NOWAIT; and it failed, but a normal select query would not.

Comment: So I guess I just need wrap my select statement with a transaction like this? 
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE SOME_TABLE IN ACCESS SHARE MODE NOWAIT;
SELECT * from SOME_TABLE;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;