# Return the result of SELECT statement in a transaction in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

I would like to do something like this:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE MY_TABLE IN ACCESS SHARE MODE NOWAIT;
SELECT * from MY_TABLE;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

but this query returns an empty ResultSet after executing the query from prepared statement in JDBC, is it possible to wrap a SELECT statement in a transaction? Or should I change approach completely?

Basically I would need it to behave exactly like the select would (performance-wise too), but fail if there is an exclusive lock on the table.

EDIT:

Some context: [Fail SELECT Query if table is locked in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897757/fail-select-query-if-table-is-locked-in-postgresql) (parent question)

Java code:

```
PreparedStatement sm = SimpleStatementWrapper.wrap(conn).prepareSelectStatementLockNowait(
        SQL,
        ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
);
ResultSet rs = sm.executeQuery();
```

```
private String wrapSql(String sql) {
    String trimmed = sql.trim();
    return "BEGIN; " +
            "LOCK TABLE PING_TASK IN ACCESS SHARE MODE NOWAIT; "
            + (trimmed.endsWith(Constant.SEMI_COLON) ? trimmed : trimmed + Constant.SEMI_COLON)
            + " COMMIT TRANSACTION;";
}


// connectionCache is the same connection that was passed in .wrap(conn)
@Override
public PreparedStatement prepareSelectStatementLockNowait(String sql) throws SQLException {
    return this.connectionCache.prepareStatement(wrapSql(sql));
}
```

Comment: A SELECT is always part of  transaction.

Comment: You posted none of your Java code, which is unfortunate because I would suggest you control the transaction from there (the client). `con.setAutoCommit(false);` and then you can use `con.commit();` (in Java). See also [The Java™ Tutorials: Using Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks I might try that, the java code is pretty straightforward, just connection.prepareStatement(sql) and resultSet = statement.executeQuery() with sql being the above sql code with basic JDBC. I will try what you suggested and see if it works and check out the documentation, thank you very much!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have checked the solution but Connection.commit() returns a void, how do I get the select result into a Result Set? I've edited the question with my Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify what I was saying in the comments, I would use JDBC to control the transaction. That might look something like,

```
private static final String LOCKSQL = "LOCK TABLE PING_TASK IN ACCESS SHARE MODE NOWAIT";

@Override
public PreparedStatement prepareSelectStatementLockNowait(String sql)
            throws SQLException {
    this.connectionCache.setAutoCommit(false);
    try (PreparedStatement ps1 = this.connectionCache.prepareStatement(LOCKSQL)) {
        ps1.execute();
    }
    return this.connectionCache.prepareStatement(sql);
}
```

Then you can use

```
ResultSet rs = sm.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // ...
}
conn.commit(); // commit the transaction
```